# Как разработчик может повлиять на добавление сайта на страницу быстрых ссылок в браузере?

Tags: html, браузер

Заметил, что некоторые сайты добавляются после первого же захода, а некоторые вообще не хотят, сколько бы не заходил (Хром). Может ли разработчик сайта повлиять на добавление сайта на страницу быстрых ссылок в браузере? Каким образом, в какую сторону смотреть?

Comment: Я думаю что это не очень логично что бы такое было возможно, а то бы все "ускоряли". Хотя может какой-то есть white-list у Google, в чём сомневаюсь, в который попадаешь за деньги. Так же возможно это как-то зависит от PR сайта. Но думаю что тут врятли вам дадут ответ, так как ну очень частный вопрос, тут надо сам исходник хрома смотреть, если он вообще в сети есть.

Comment: Это верно. Но отличия в добавлении на страницу замечал не раз. Вот зашел на сайт Всемирной организации здравоохранения (в жизни туда не заходил) - нашел инфо нужную - сайт сразу в закладках. А мой сайт, который тестю и захожу туда по 30 раз за день - никак не хочет добавлять.

Comment: Скорее всего от PR зависит. Можно тестовым путём проверить.